# Jersey REST image GET issue

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, get, jersey

i have a simple question.

Lets say that i want to download multiple specific images when i call my GET method in my REST API from a directory, given that i have their names. eg.

../folder

```
name1.png
name2.png
name3.png
name4.png
```

And i want to download name2.png, name3.png.

Everything that i could dig up was regarding only 1 image per call, like this:

```
@Path("/image")
public class ImageService {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "c:\\picture.png";

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("image/png")
    public Response getFile() {

        File file = new File(FILE_PATH);

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=image_from_server.png");
        return response.build();

    }

}
```

The thing that has come to my mind is to send a zip or something like that. Could anyone tell me if this is possible, and if it is how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: zip file sounds good

Comment: It is *typical* to use multiple HTTP calls for this. Why are you wanting to batch them so badly?

Comment: Because i am using appcelerator platform to build my client app which is not very bright :D And, now im looking into all possibilities.